# Custom Action script in SharePoint Designer 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, custom-actions

I am using SharePoint Designer 2013 to edit a list page. I am hoping to add a button to the List Item Menu which will run a script, editing the item.

The only options displayed are "Navigate to form", "Initiate workflow", and "Navigate to URL."

I have seen posts referencing the code behind a custom action which is accessible in Visual Studio. Is there any good way of making a Custom Action run a script without having to install and configure Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind a Custom Action to a SharePoint Designer workflow, which will then edit the item for you. You can either allow users to enter in their own info in the workflow initiation form for use in the workflow, or allow the workflow to determine what info to put.

Comment: Hmmm...I guess I will have to do that. I was hoping to avoid a workflow because I already have a script I can reuse from a form page. Thanks